# Call Yelp API through ajax in node.js causes 404 error

Tags: javascript, node.js, ajax, api, yelp

I call Yelp API in backend node.js with ajax method. I use get method to get the data, and I'm sure that my headers and get parameters are correct. Don't know why there's a 404 error.

Here's my ajax call:
[image]

This is the error that I get:
[image]

How to avoid this error?

Comment: Seems that you cannot call this API from within your web page, because it does not support [CORS](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/CORS).

Comment: I'm afraid it's not a CORS problem, because I already call a Google Geo location API, it's successful

Comment: If the Google location API supports CORS, that does not mean that the Yelp API also supports it. It's the decision of each individual API whether to support CORS.